# Java object that encapsulates all primitives -- useful in OutputStreams

Tags: java, class, standards, abstract-class, primitive

I have a program that receives binary data, and depending on its heading, represents either a `float`, `int`, `double`, `char`, `string`, etc.

In the program, I utilize the `ByteBuffer` class to take that `byte[]` and then use the `getFloat()` or `getInt()` etc. methods to extract out the contents into a usable form.

I'd like to pass the value from `getFloat()` or `getInt()` to the `System.out.println()` efficiently, without using a switch or if/else statements for all the possibilities.

Since `println()` can accept a `Float`, `Int` or anything, it would be nice if there was a Java Object I could use that I can stuff the `getXXX()` data into, regardless of the type, and then return the value into the `println()` function.

Only problem is, I don't know of any Java class that does this and my Google searches are dry. Anyone know of a class?

I suppose I could write one, but I try to do everything the Java certified way first.

EDIT: here is an example with my current code:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(dat.message);

if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("float")) {

    System.out.println("Message: " + buffer.getFloat());

} else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("int")) {

    System.out.println("Message: " + buffer.getInt());

} else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("char")) {

    System.out.println("Message: " + buffer.getChar());

} else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("long")) {

    System.out.println("Message: " + buffer.getLong());

} else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")) {

    System.out.println("Message: " + buffer.get());

} else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {

    String str = new String(dat.message);
    System.out.println("Message: " + str);

}
```

Too ugly for me, there's gotta be a better way with Java.

Comment: Why not use the Object class?

Comment: Maybe I should... I noticed this is a method in ByteBuffer: Class<? extends dat.datType> func = buffer.getClass(); the getClass(). Not sure exactly how to use it though

Comment: There is probably a case for the visitor pattern here. But it is hard to tell what the practical use of your `dat` object is since it seems to just hold byte data and a String representing the type. Almost like you could quite simply convert that data to boxed types at a higher level in the application. Or make subclasses for the allowable concrete types. Then you wouldn't even need the visitor, just a proper implementation of `toString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public Object getValue(Dat dat) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(dat.message);

    if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("float")) {
        return buffer.getFloat();
    } else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("int")) {
        return buffer.getInt();
    } else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("char")) {
        return buffer.getChar();
    } else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("long")) {
        return buffer.getLong();
    } else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("boolean")) {
        return buffer.get() != 0;
    } else if (dat.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("string")) {
        return new String(dat.message);
    }
}

// ...

System.out.println("Message: " + getValue(dat));
```

A `float` will get auto-boxed into a `Float` which is an `Object`.
An `int` will get auto-boxed into an `Integer` which is an `Object`.
And so on.

Comment: Cool, although its pretty similar to my original solution, it does let me create a static method elsewhere in my code and not clog my algorithm method.

Comment: You can achieve the same functionality much more neatly with an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(dat.message);
System.out.println("Message: " + buffer);
```

All objects in Java are instances of some class that inherits from Object. Since `println` accepts `Object`s, you don't have to worry about what type you are passing in.

---

Edit: Can you provide a declaration for `dat`?

Comment: Really? That's all.. so the getXXX() method was superfluous?

Comment: I take that back, it didn't work.... I accidentally left the getFloat() in there...

This is what pops out when I don't specify getXXX()

    Message: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]

Comment: dat is my own class that just holds a bunch of data. That's all. It has shorts, floats, ints, strings, etc.

Comment: @EricS Yeah, I forgot that buffers can't automatically convert to the right datatype. You can make your solution lot shorter with reflection but that may be overkill for your purposes.

Comment: Yeah, learning more about reflection is high on my list of Java skills